# Error: invalid conversion from int to int(*)[4] in function calls

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I'm working on a homework project where I have to do a modified preorder traversal through an array-based tree and I need to pass the array to the function in order to use it but I keep getting an error in the function saying that it's an invalid conversion from `int` to `int(*)[4]` and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here's a copy of my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>

    char code[10];

    void preOrder(int tree[][4], int index, int treeDepth)
    {
            int tempIndex;
            if(tree[index][2] == -1 && tree[index][3] == -1)
            {
                    std::cout << char(tree[index][1]) << ": ";

                    for(int i = 0; i < treeDepth; i++)
                            std::cout << code[i];

                    std::cout << "\n"
            }
            else
            {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {
                            code[treeDepth] = 0;
                            tempIndex = tree[index][2];
                            preOrder(tree[index][2], tempIndex, treeDepth + 1);
                            code[treeDepth] = 1;
                            tempIndex = tree[index][2];
                            preOrder(tree[index][3], tempIndex, treeDepth + 1);
                    }
             }

             return;
    }

    int main()
    {
            int numNodes = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
            int root = 0, treeDepth = 0;
            int numcols = 4;

            std::fstream inFile;
            inFile.open("tree.dat");

            inFile >> root;
            inFile >> numNodes;

            int huffmanTree[numNodes][numCols];

            for(i = 0; i < numNodes; i++)
                    for(j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
                            inFile >> huffmanTree[i][j];

            preOrder(huffmanTree, root, treeDepth);

            inFile.close();
            return 0;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
And also I can't use pointers and I can also declare huffmanTree as global but couldn't figure out how to get that to work either. And also sorry for the way everything it placed. This is my first time posting.

The errors are:

```
ola.cpp: In function ‘void preOrder(int (*)[4], int, int)’:
ola.cpp:28:53: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int (*)[4]’ [-fpermissive]
ola.cpp:10:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void preOrder(int (*)[4], int, int)’ [-fpermissive]
ola.cpp:31:53: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int (*)[4]’ [-fpermissive]
ola.cpp:10:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void preOrder(int (*)[4], int, int)’ [-fpermissive]
ola.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ola.cpp:67:39: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)numCols) + -1)) + 1)]’ to ‘int (*)[4]’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void preOrder(int (*)[4], int, int)’
```

Comment: The expression `tree[index][2]` is an `int`, not an `int(*)[4]`, I'm not sure if the error could be clearer.

Comment: Here's the errors:

Comment: `numCols` in your code is undeclared. Is that a typo, or are there more errors you're not telling us about?

Comment: The line numbers in your error output don't match up with the lines in the code you posted.

Comment: Your code has a lot more errors than what your question would lead most people to believe, including nonsensical calls to `preOrder` with incorrect types. Unfortunately, this looks like homework as well.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your error on line 67: in Standard C++ this is not permitted:

```
int huffmanTree[numNodes][numCols];
```

Only constant expressions may be used as array dimensions.

Some compilers implement a non-standard extension to allow this sort of array, but not very well: it appears that, for your compiler, this extension doesn't extend to passing the array to a function that expects an array of fixed width.

Possibly it would fix your problem to use `const int numcols = 4;` instead.

---

The errors on line 28 and 31 are due to calling `preOrder(tree[index][2]` .  Your first argument is an `int` but the function expects pointer to array.  If you're trying to create a slice of the array starting at some particular row and column - that actually isn't possible. You'd have to pass `tree, index, 2, tempIndex, treeDepth + 1` instead, adding 2 more parameters to your function which indicate the starting point; and modifying the function logic accordingly.